# Schema.org and webmaster tools rich snippet tool

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, schema.org

I am at a loss as to which schema.org type to use. Can anyone suggest anything? Specific question are at the bottom of this post and obvious. My website has been online for four years and has thousands of individual reviews. The website is a directory of places where a certain activity happens. Those places can be churches, city parks, fair grounds, retail stores, restaurants, national forests, gas stations, you name it! My website provides a write up of the location and the facilities that it provides in relation to the activities. The activity may or may not pertain to the location's assumed function (ie. my users aren't eating at the restaurant). Users who perform the activity come to my site and leave reviews about the place. Users may rate also the location but ratings are not part of the user reviews themselves.

If I use hreview-aggregates, the rich text and stars show up in the google testing tool. If I only use the follow from schema.org, the tool doesn't show the snippet in the but recognizes the formatting:

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  <span itemprop="name">The Hubcap Place</span>
  <span itemprop="itemreviewed">Hubcap City</span>
  <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> stars -
  <span itemprop="reviewCount">3077</span> reviews
</div>
```

Everything looks great if I change it to

```
<title>My Site</title>
<div class="entry" itemtype="http://schema.org/localBusiness" itemscope="">
  <span itemprop="name">The Hubcap Place</span>
  <span itemprop="itemreviewed">Hubcap City</span>
  <span itemprop="author">Ellie</span>
  <span itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope="" itemprop="aggregateRating">
    <meta content="3.2" itemprop="ratingvalue">
    <meta content="18" itemprop="ratingcount">
  </span>
</div>
```

I don't think that localbusiness is appropriate. Some of locations are just an empty spot in the middle of a field. Also, schema.org/localBusiness makes me feel like I should own it. schema.org/Place seems most appropriate but doesn't display the rich text snippet in the tool. Same thing with schema.org/Review. If I use it as the main wrapper, the snippet doesn't display. Other main wrappers that do work are Product and Restaurant. I would appreciate any advice that you can give.

- Is Place failing because of my markup?
- What would be a good type for the wrapper? The wrapper is required right?
- Should I just pick a main wrapper even if it doesn't exactly fit
  everything?
- Can I use both hreview-aggragate(microformat) and schema.org
  at the same time? That's what I am doing right now, and it shows up fine in the testing
  tool, but I have heard that you shouldn't. Is that still the current
  advice?

It should also be noted that when I use data-vocabulary.org/Review with its proper syntax, everything displays fine in the tool as well...I am just having trouble with schema.org

Answer (score 5):

You can use schema.org markup for reviewed item and data-vocabulary markup for review item. Also note that if you use reviewCount you need provide marked-up reviews on this page too.

Answer (score -1):

If I follow your question rightly, I think this is part of an answer to help clarify

```
<div class="entry" itemtype="http://schema.org/localBusiness" itemscope="">
 <span itemprop="name">My Site</span>
</div>
```

LocalBusiness is used to describe YOU and your Name Address and Phone (Your Contact details)

As far as I can determine should be separated from other "itemtypes" which can be called separately and the page can have nested "itemtypes".

```
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
 <span itemprop="name">The Hubcap Place</span> "If this is the place being reviewed"
 <span itemprop="itemreviewed">Hubcap City</span> "Would not need this as it repeats"
 <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span> stars -
 <span itemprop="reviewCount">3077</span> reviews
```

These would indicate the Item/Place being reviewed, who reviewed the place, their rating, aggregated ratings by all contributors and how many reviews the place has.
i.e. a separate itemtype call to delineate the information within that part of the page.

I think the mistake or misunderstanding you have is the one "itemtype" will cover everything.

Hope this helps, I've only been looking at this myself for the last week.